# How to read backup file of Wechat chats on Mac/PC?

Tags: backup, wechat

I have the backup of my chats from Wechat running on an Android phone. How can I read the chats in that backup on my Mac/PC? Is there a Mac/PC application which can read the WeChat backup and give me plain text output?

I noticed some people claim(https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-print-WeChat-conversation-s-history-and-chat-logs) they have done it with "Cok Free iTunes Backup Extractor". However they seem to be using an iPhone and not Android.

Any pointers on this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about using an Amdroid app not a web application as it’s defined in [help/on-topic]. Try [android.se].